# Space values in line graph by Y value instead of equally

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

If I have a table of data that looks like this:

```
Time (seconds)  Data
1.1             4
1.2             4
1.31            7
1.4             8
1.91            11
2               9
2.1             5
2.22            12
```

...with the values I want to use for the Y axis (time column) not evenly spaced, and create a line graph using the first column to create the Horizontal Axis Labels, and the second column as the data series, Excel give me a graph that looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/n6qJFjs.png]

...with the data points all equally spaced and the Y axis markers unevenly spaced.

What I want is a graph where the Y axis markers are evenly spaced and the distance between points on it is variable, somewhat like this (although with all the data points aligned correctly instead of just stretching in the middle for the large gap):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xicFa.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the scatter chart.

I use non-english Excel, so look at attached image, where to find the correct button.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: THX for correction.